# S3 keys from a QT/C++ client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have an application that is written in C++/QT that sits on client machines all around the world and the client uploads files to Amazon S3, what is the best way to authenticate with Amazon without actually including the Amazon key on every client, is there any way to generate a unique key for each client (1000s of potential clients)?

Would it make more sense to send everything to an intermediate server or proxy and then from there upload the files to Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0):

The optimum way to implement this is to follow the below steps:

Step1: Allow your clients to upload files to intermediate server.

Step2: Store your AWS s3 bucket user credentials in the intermediate server file or database.

Step3: Upload the files from intermediate server to the Amazon s3 bucket.

Hope it helps....